# Basic issue with ReactJS setting state in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-state

Hi I am new to React and I just can't wrap my head around some basic things.

One of these things is the following.

Why does the state of itemData change when calling the function with onChange on the textarea element as in this example:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function Createitem() {
  const [itemData, setitemData] = useState([]);
  const handleitemData = (e) => {
    setitemData({
      itemTime: Date.now(),
      itemText: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("item", itemData);
  }, [itemData]);
  return (
    <div className="itemBox">
      <div>
        <form>
          <textarea
            onChange={handleitemData}
            placeholder="What you have in mind ..."
          ></textarea>
          <button type="submit">item</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Createitem;
```

But not when calling the function with onSubmit on the form element as in this example:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function Createitem() {
  const [itemData, setitemData] = useState([]);
  const handleitemData = (e) => {
    setitemData({
      itemTime: Date.now(),
      itemText: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("item", itemData);
  }, [itemData]);
  return (
    <div className="itemBox">
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleitemData}>
          <textarea placeholder="What you have in mind ..."></textarea>
          <button type="submit">item</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Createitem;
```

I know the React way is if that does not work try something else but I am trying to actually understand what is going on.

I apreciate your response.

Comment: Is your form submitting and causing a page reload?

Comment: Hi Chris Farmer,

Thank you for your reply!

If I remove e.preventDefault(); the page does reload.

I guess I removed it while breaking my head on this but the issue is really that the key itemText is undefined when I call the function with onSubmit however the key itemText is not empty when I call the function with onChange on the textarea.

I apreciate your input!

Answer (score 0):

You must prevent the default behavior of the browser on submit:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function Createitem() {
  const [itemData, setitemData] = useState([]);
  const handleitemData = (e) => {
//The line below is necessary
    e.preventDefault() 
    setitemData({
      itemTime: Date.now(),
      itemText: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("item", itemData);
  }, [itemData]);
  return (
    <div className="itemBox">
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleitemData}>
          <textarea placeholder="What you have in mind ..."></textarea>
          <button type="submit">item</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Createitem;
```

attached is a sandbox to see it in action https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-lederberg-3oj1w?file=/src/App.js:0-630

Comment: Hi Robert Terrell,

Thank you for your answer.

I actually had the e.preventDefault() before but I guess I removed it while breaking my head on this.

Basically with the e.preventDefault() I do have an object with the state set as an object but the key itemText is undefined when I call the function with onSubmit however the key itemText is not empty when I call the function with onChange on the textarea.

This is what is puzzling me.

I apreaciate your feedback! You seem very knowledgeable.